# Composer And Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

I'm a little new to Composer so this is just a general question. I've been developing a WP plugin, and I'm requiring a few libraries in via composer. I've uploaded the plugin to a server and I'm having problems. Am I required to run composer install on the server as well as on my localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to manage your dependencies with composer during development, you can do so.

But none of the WP workflows (neither the base installation, nor plugins) use composer. WordPress simply expects a folder with your code, it doesn't care about any of the internals, as long as you [follow some simple rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

If your plugin is public, you will have to submit it to the WordPress SVN, but there's no such thing as a build process. Also, WP plugin users will usually neither be interested in, nor have the possibility to, execute composer.

It is up to you if you create your own build process before committing to the WP SVN, or if you create your plugin in a way that it can run from your development code.

However, if you “build” your code before committing it to WP SVN (e.g. creating cache files, removing development-only dependencies etc.), you could run into discussions with people who insist on getting the original sources, too.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't release at all if it required people to run composer, but what I'm wondering is if a project that uses composer and already has the dependencies installed locally via composer.json needs to run composer install again once its on the server. My plugin is heavily dependent on the autoloading capabilities of composer so thats why I need it more than anything

Comment: Simple answer: No they don't need composer, if you add all the libaries pulled by composer with your plugin and add it altogether into the VCS (which you of course do). If they already have the libs, they can't use them, because the libs are not installed globally, but per project. If you need a more verbose answer, let me know what you're missing, I'll update my post.

Comment: Little correction: http://akrabat.com/php/global-installation-of-php-tools-with-composer/ so it is possible. But I haven't worked with it yet, so I cannot say how it performs and if it could help you.